# synchronous TCP connection using CFStream or NSStream

Tags: objective-c, ios

I try to create class for the **synchronous** TCP connection using CFStream or NSStream without directly using the CFSocket. But I can't find the right way or smple to solve this task with these classes. Please help!

Comment: I made a sockets class, as a wrapper of the BSD sockets library that you may be interested in, it works on iOS too. Supports NSFileHandle for reading / writing, and its synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Create your socket using the `socket` system call, then pass it to `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket`.